# How to fetch data only when the modal loads

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-modal

I have a react component let's say: app.js ( parent component ) that has a child component which renders a react bootstrap modal component. the parent component fetch data from redux using react hook like that:

```
  useEffect(() => { props.dispatch(actions.loadAll());},[]);
```

and then data are being passed to show in my modal component. I am handling the modal visibility with "show" and "onShow" state. Is there anyways, I can avoid loading the data in my parent component and loads only after the modal component loads and display data there? any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `useEffect` will only execute after initial render is done. So the modal would be rendered by the time `useEffect` runs.

Comment: Is it possible to tell me more about this. I can see from the browser network tab that the data loads even though modal is not loaded

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `useEffect` hook that depends on your state `show`.

```
useEffect(() => { props.dispatch(actions.loadAll());},[show]);
```

Using this chunk of code when the `show` state changes,  the `useEffect` runs. So when your modal opens, your data is loaded.

Comment: you meant that I should declare "useEffect" to the modal component (child) or the app.js ( parent component)

Comment: Any component that owns your state.

Comment: Okay,will give it a try

Comment: I have used that but and saw the data loads and update the store only when the modal renders but I do have a problems now accessing the state from the reducers. seems like,I can't access the state immediately...

Comment: If you would like to access data immediately, you should get data in useEffect without any dependency. When using useEffect with dependency, it doesn't call until its dependency will change.
If my answer can help you, please accept it.

Comment: Is it possible to give a sort example of it? what do you mean by without dependency. In my case, my parent component need to access the data from redux store using mapStateToProps

Comment: It will load everytime you open the modal and close the modal.  So you will be loading the data too many times.  As such its not a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Like s.hesam said

use condition to load the data only if the modal open.

I add the condition if the modal open the first time - fisrtTimeLoad

fisrtTimeLoad - can be the data in the state that exist and you put it as another condition.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (show && fisrtTimeLoad) props.dispatch(actions.loadAll());
  }, [show, fisrtTimeLoad]);
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted answer.  It prevents multiple data loads.  You might want to correct the spelling mistake though (first)